# SSL certificates on NGINX - is combining the two .crt files neccessary?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I had a task to renew ssl certificates on a few websites, all went well I tested and was about to close the task when I noticed:

```
#if on nginx prepare your certificate by combining the two files given to 
#you by godaddy
cat yourdomain.com.crt gd_bundle.crt > yourdomain.com_combined.crt
```

This was not mentionned on godaddy's website per se, but I found it in other threads so I did as suggested above, but did not see any noticeable difference.

I am curious as to what difference there is in combining the two .crt, verses just using the one .crt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional bundle is for intermediate CA certs. They represent a "chain of trust"

From https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO4261.html

> An intermediate CA certificate is a subordinate certificate issued by the trusted root specifically to issue end-entity server certificates. The result is a trust-chain that begins at the trusted root CA, through the intermediate and finally ending with the SSL certificate issued to you

If GoDaddy or others specify intermediate bundles, then include or merge them as specified.